# Is a SQL trigger is automatically added to sys.trigger table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, sql-server-2012

I need to create a monitoring on all trigers in my SQL server with the possibility of disable them via a script.

So I made a script to select all triggers but the result of the script is not correct, it shows me 30 triggers while I have 162 triggers distributed among 6 databases.

Here is a part of the script to select all the triggers:

```
use master
go

select * from sys.objects
where type = 'TR'
```

Is there a query or something to do to add the others triggers to the sys.objects table ?

Comment: It only shows you from the current database. For other databases you need `select * from OtherDB.sys.triggers`. Also if you don't have the right permissions you won't see them

Comment: Also, do not forget that DDL triggers exists in addition by DML tgriggers. For this case, you must query the system view sys.server_triggers

Comment: @Charlieface Yes your answer allows me to find all triggers in my differents database.

Comment: You should have a button to accept this marked duplicate and close the question